# Not able to return CSV file in MVC action. Not Cannot access a closed Streamable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csvhelper

On a ASP.NET MVC action I am trying to return a CSV file with users info:

```
  IList<UserModel> users = _repository.GetUsers();

  MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream;
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream)) {
      using (CsvWriter csv = new CsvWriter(writer)) {
        csv.Configuration.With(x => {
          x.AutoMap<UserModel>();
          x.RegisterClassMap<UserModelCsvMapper>();
        });            
        csv.WriteRecords(reply.Users);
        writer.Flush();
        return File(stream, "text/csv", "Users.csv");
      }
    }
```

And I have the following mapper:

```
public class UserModelCsvMapper : CsvClassMap<UserModel> {
  public override void CreateMap() {
    Map(x => x.Name).Name("Name");
    Map(x => x.Email).Name("Email");
    Map(x => x.Linked).Name("Linked");
  } // CreateMap
} // UserModelCsvMapper
```

My CSV writer seems empty and when I return the Stream I get the error:

```
((System.IO.Stream)(stream)).WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

And I get the error page:

```
Cannot access a closed Stream.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.
```

**UPDATE: Adding Stack Trace**

Cannot access a closed Stream.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.]
   System.IO._*Error.StreamIsClosed() +57
   System.IO.MemoryStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +10909062
   System.Web.Mvc.FileStreamResult.WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.FileResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +296
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +106
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass2b.b_*1c() +321
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass21.b_*1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b*_1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b_*15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b*_5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9514928
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: It'd be beneficial to others that find your question if the problem remains intact. What I mean is don't edit your question to show the correct code, it should show what you did wrong so others can learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your using statement is closing the memory stream that you're returning in your FileResult.

This should fix it. Declare the `MemoryStream` outside of the block. It will be closed by the framework once the stream has been fully written to the `Response` stream (although it's currently not essential to close `MemoryStream`. They get cleaned up properly when they're garbage collected.

```
IList<UserModel> users = _repository.GetUsers();

var stream = new MemoryStream();
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream)) {
  using (CsvWriter csv = new CsvWriter(writer)) {
      csv.Configuration.With(x => {
      x.AutoMap<UserModel>();
      x.RegisterClassMap<UserModelCsvMapper>();  
    });            
    csv.WriteRecords(reply.Users)
    writer.Flush();
    return File(stream, "text/csv", "Users.csv");
  }
}
```

Alternately you can use the Byte[] overload of the FileResponse.

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
using (CsvWriter csv = new CsvWriter(writer) {
  csv.Configuration.With(x => {
    x.AutoMap<UserModel>();
    x.RegisterClassMap<UserModelCsvMapper>();  
  })        

  //use the users that you just retrieved from the repository
  csv.WriteRecords(users)
  writer.Flush();

  return File(stream.ToArray(), "text/csv", "Users.csv");
}
```

Comment: Is it the same exception? On what line is it thrown? Can you attach the stack trace?

Comment: Just added ... If I remove all usings I don't get the error anymore ... But the CSV file is empty which is strange because I have 3 records in Users but they don't get inside the CSV ... But I see no error on my mapping.

Comment: Try the Byte[] overload of the File method like in my last edit, that way there's no risk of the stream being closed.

Comment: Also, you're passing the reply.Users to your CsvWriter instead of the users variable that you retrieve from the repository.

Comment: By using ToArray everything is solved ... I can even use "Using MemoryStream ..." ... This is quite strange isn't it? ... The reply.Users was a mistake when I copied the code. I wrote here a simplified version of it ...

Comment: I noticed the bug in your code. See my final edit. You had a bracket misplaced in your using CsvWriter line and an extra semicolon which meant only the CsvWriter config was happening in the correct scope. The reason ToArray works is that ToArray doesn't check whether the MemoryStream is closed. In fact closing a MemoryStream has no effect currently.

Comment: It's because the stream position is at the end. Doing `stream.Position = 0` will make it so you can just pass the stream to `File` directly.